# Asp.net Head Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to write head tag.

i need create dynamic

```
<head id="htmlHead" runat="server">

</head>
```

code behind:

```
htmlHead.InnerText = "<script src=\"Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
```

not work pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The head tag is a server control, so you do one of two things:

```
Literal scriptLiteral = new Literal();
scriptLiteral.Text = "<script src=\"Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
Header.Controls.Add(scriptLiteral);
```

Or the MUCH preferred:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("JQuery-DatePicker", "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
htmlHead.InnerHtml
```